# Linq - doesn't start with any prefix in range of prefixes

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create a Linq query that would have the following logic:

```
IEnumerable<string> prefixes = GetListOfPrefixesFromSomewhere();
IQueryable<Record> myQuery = GetAllRecordsFromRepository();
foreach (string prefix in prefixes)
{
  myQuery = myQuery.Where(x => !x.Field.StartsWith(prefix));
}
```

This would obviously result in a large IQueryable which can then be executed.

Is there a nice elegant way to express this is a single Linq statement?

Comment: "to express this is a single Linq statement?" Does that mean the current version is working?

Comment: Yes - this is a refactoring question, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at least *try* this:

```
// Only call ToList if you need to, of course... but I think EF/LINQ To SQL
// will need it as a list (or array)
List<string> prefixes = GetListOfPrefixesFromSomewhere().ToList();

IQueryable<Record> query = GetAllRecordsFromRepository()
             .Where(x => !prefixes.Any(prefix => x.Field.StartsWith(prefix)));
```

Quite what the SQL will look like, I don't know - but I think it's *logically* what you want, which is usually a good start.

Comment: Skeet, I was hoping to get an answer from you. My question is blessed!

Comment: Regarding your caveat, that's fine - I was interested in how you express the requirement in Linq. What the Linq provider will make of it, hell knows!